# Failed to parse app's Info.plist appcelerator studio error

Tags: ios, xcode, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have newly installed xCode and appcelerator studio following is the configuration :

```
Operating System
  Name                        = Mac OS X
  Version                     = 10.11.6
  Architecture                = 64bit
  # CPUs                      = 4
  Memory                      = 8589934592
Node.js
  Node.js Version             = 0.12.7
  npm Version                 = 2.11.3
Titanium CLI
  CLI Version                 = 5.0.9
Titanium SDK
  SDK Version                 = 5.0.2.GA
  SDK Path                    = /Users/neosoft/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.0.2.GA
  Target Platform             = iphone
```

Now when I am trying to run demo iOS app then it throwing following error:

```
Failed to parse app's Info.plist: /Appcelator Projects/demo/build/iphone/build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/demo.app/Info.plist
```

I have tried with XCode 7 and 8 as well then also it showing same error.

can anyone help me to resolve it ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't know the reason for XCode 7 but for XCode 8 the problem is your sdk of titanium. You're using "5.0.2.GA" but currently the only version of titanium that supports XCode 8 is 5.5.*.GA (at this time of writing it is 5.5.1.GA).

So just set the sdk to 5.5.*.GA and it should solve your problem. :)

Source:
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-23518

Answer (score 0):

I had that two days ago.  Logged out of studio (clicking on the user name in the lower right hand corner), rebooted, logged back in, cleaned project and everything worked fine after that.

Comment: And instant karma for me!  I went to work on a different project and starting getting this error.  Tried what I suggested and it did not resolve either.  Found this JIRA ticket, https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-23518, and found I had not changed this project to 5.5.0.  Did so and it compiled and ran on the sim just fine.  Sorry to waste your time!